# Docker with Tensorflow

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow

I try to use docker. I got this to start:

```
~/tensorflow$ docker run -u $(id -u):$(id -g) -it -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:nightly-py3-jupyter
```

That prints out:

```
________                               _______________                
___  __/__________________________________  ____/__  /________      __
__  /  _  _ \_  __ \_  ___/  __ \_  ___/_  /_   __  /_  __ \_ | /| / /
_  /   /  __/  / / /(__  )/ /_/ /  /   _  __/   _  / / /_/ /_ |/ |/ / 
/_/    \___//_/ /_//____/ \____//_/    /_/      /_/  \____/____/|__/


You are running this container as user with ID 1000 and group 1000,
which should map to the ID and group for your user on the Docker host. Great!

[I 05:42:44.497 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/IPython/paths.py:68: UserWarning: IPython parent '/' is not a writable location, using a temp directory.
  " using a temp directory.".format(parent))
[I 05:42:45.970 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /tf
```

Which IPython parent '/' is not writeable?
There is also no directory /tf on my system.

```
[I 05:42:45.971 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 05:42:45.971 NotebookApp] http://(87eb400fcb15 or 127.0.0.1):8888/?token=52ea6e8417f21a2cf0463ce147747f79ff6a7e290014a768
[I 05:42:45.971 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 05:42:45.975 NotebookApp] 

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-12-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://(87eb400fcb15 or 127.0.0.1):8888/?token=52ea6e8417f21a2cf0463ce147747f79ff6a7e290014a768
[I 05:44:25.595 NotebookApp] 302 GET /?token=52ea6e8417f21a2cf0463ce147747f79ff6a7e290014a768 (172.17.0.1) 1.23ms
[I 05:44:44.277 NotebookApp] Writing notebook-signing key to /.local/share/jupyter/notebook_secret
```

It says it wants to write "notebook_cookie_secret", however, there is no directory runtime within jupyter. Permissions of jupyter:

```
~/.local/share$ ls -la jupyter/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 ronald ronald 4096 Jan 29 09:10 .
drwx------ 30 ronald ronald 4096 Apr  8 09:39 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 ronald ronald 4096 Jan 29 09:10 kernels
drwxr-xr-x  3 ronald ronald 4096 Jan 29 09:10 nbextensions
```

To access file:/// is not possible, since the file does not exist.

I can access the notebook via 127.0.0.1/ ...

I open the three files in a different tab on my browser. That starts the two files basic_classification.ipynb and basic_text_classification.ipynb

There I am. I don't know what should happen, or how can I make something happen. I thought, maybe it needs time, but even after one hour it shows just "Running". Please give me some hints.